# NextGen Gallery Plugin Borders around album thumbnail

Tags: css, wordpress

NextGen has made quite a lot of changes lately and one of them is making it more difficult to override their CSS with a string of selectors. I have a series of albums on a client site that is showing the NextGen borders. I can't seem to get rid of them with:

1. A custom id layer on the page around the content and using that layer in the selectors
2. Their suggestion to add Place any custom stylesheets in wp-content/ngg_styles

I hate to inconvenience my client by installing a different gallery, but I will do so, if I can't find a way to override the NextGen CSS.

Thank you for your help!